# Create a div with 4 responsive buttons with text and logos bootstrap 5

Tags: html, css, button, bootstrap-5, responsive

I have got a HTML/CSS/Bootstrap 5/JS and Rust/Actix-web webapp. [The code](https://github.com/asensio-project/trivial_packager)

In the index page I have got a navbar and a div with four buttons in the centre (vertical, horizontal). The actual mechanism for resizing the buttons is getting the size of the text above and divide by 4. That's the width of the button. But there are two problems: if the name of the user is small the buttons will be small and that in medium size devices, e.g.: tablets the size of the font is as bigger as in my laptop because it's very hard to exactly configure the @media screen.

As result, I have overflow with in the buttons.

[image: Big screen]

[image: Medium screen]

```js
let divElement = document.getElementById("welcome");
let buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('button-group-element')
let buttons_array = Array.from(buttons)
let elemWidth = divElement.offsetWidth / buttons_array.length;
for (i = 0; i < buttons_array.length; i++) {
  if (i != 0) {
    buttons_array[i].style.marginLeft = elemWidth * i + "px"
  }
  buttons_array[i].style.width = elemWidth + "px"
}
```

```css
html,
body {
 position: relative;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}

body {
 display: flex;
 position: absolute;
 align-items: center;
 bottom: 40%;
 justify-content: center;
 background-color: #0000;
}

#welcome {
 text-align: center;
 }


.button-group-element {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  height: 40%;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 707px) {
  .button-group-element {
    font-size: 2em;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 706px) {
  .button-group-element {
    font-size: 1.3em;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.5/font/bootstrap-icons.css">

<h1 id="welcome">Bienvenido John Doe!</h1>
<div class="button-group">
<button onclick="window.location.href='/add_question'" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary button-group-element"><i class="bi bi-plus-circle"></i> <br>Nueva Pregunta</button><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary button-group-element"
  onclick="window.location = '/modify_question'"><i class="bi bi-pen"></i> <br>Modificar Pregunta</button><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary button-group-element" onclick="window.location = '/student_question'"><i class="bi bi-mortarboard"></i> <br>Preguntas de los Alumnos</button>
<button
  type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary button-group-element" onclick="window.location = '/statics'"><i class="bi bi-bar-chart"></i> <br>Estadistica</button> </div>
```

Comment: [Never link "here".](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/06/links-should-never-say-click-here/)

Comment: Also, you're using buttons as links, which is bad practice. Use anchors, and style them using button classes if you like.

Comment: Please update the demo above to show the problem. Why are you using absolute positioning? That's often problematic and unnecessary.

Comment: The code is very long for posting it here, for that reason I just put the link to github. I am using absolute positioning because is the only way that worked for me for centering the buttons. The problem is that it isn't responsive.

Comment: You need to pare it down to a representative example. The situation doesn't look that complicated. You're probably just missing some container markup. See [ask].

Comment: From a UX point of view... On smaller screens having a segmented control like that is not great. You're already using Bootstrap, why not leverage their grid system to stack the buttons for smaller devices?

Comment: Yes, that will be great and cleaner! In the beginning I though on that but I cannot get it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per your comment indicating you'd like to stack the elements on smaller devices to avoid the overflow problem, this should be what you're looking for.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.5/font/bootstrap-icons.css">

<h1 id="welcome">Bienvenido John Doe!</h1>
<!-- You're already pulling in Bootstrap. By applying the `row` class, 
you're able to leverage their grid classes -->
<div class="button-group row">
  <!-- Adding the `col-md-3` class will make the element take 3/12 (1/4) of 
  the parent's width. Adding the `md` piece makes this only apply for
  medium screen sizes and larger. When going to a smaller device, by default
  each element takes the full parent width
 -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary button-group-element col-md-3">
    <i class="bi bi-plus-circle"></i><br>
    Nueva Pregunta
  </button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary button-group-element col-md-3">
    <i class="bi bi-pen"></i><br>
    Modificar Pregunta
  </button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary button-group-element col-md-3">
    <i class="bi bi-mortarboard"></i><br>
    Preguntas de los Alumnos
  </button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary button-group-element col-md-3">
    <i class="bi bi-bar-chart"></i><br>
    Estadistica
  </button>
</div>
```

I also removed all of the provided CSS and JS code to get this to work.

Comment: Thanks, it works very good for small and medium devices but for laptops it's small.

Comment: @Juanjo Could you provide more detail about the issue you're having?

Comment: Yes, what happens now is that for mobiles looks very well and fit but for big devices like laptops is like too small, I'm referring it isn't well embedded.